# Database design for time dependent fields

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I am making a MySQL database and am fairly confident I know how to normalize it. However, there is an issue I am not sure how to deal with.

Say I have a table

```
users
----------
user_id primary key
some_field
some_field2
start_date
user_level
```

Now, user_level gives the user's level, which can be 1,2,3,4,5 say. But as time passes the user may change levels. Obviously if they change levels I can simply do an UPDATE to the users table. But I want to keep a historical record of the users' past levels

For this reason, I am considering a new table called user_level_history

```
user_level_history
--------------
id autoincrement primary key
user_id
level_start_date
```

and then modify the users table:

```
users
----------
user_id primary key
some_field
some_field2
start_date
user_level_history_id
```

Then to get the user's current level I check the

```
user_level_history_id = user_level_history.id
```

And to get the user's history I can SELECT from user_level_history all rows with the user_id and order chronologically.

Is this the standard way to do this? I can't imagine I'm the first person to come across this problem.

One more point: I am imagining less than 5000 users. Would having many, many more users require a different solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that could be designed like this:
**Have a table for level** information  like value(1,2,3,4,5) , description ... 
**Have an association table for user_level_history** containing user_id, level_id,level_start_date  ... 
**Have a foreign key from level table to user table with the role user-active-level**.

You need to develop a mechanism that when user level is changing, inserting to history table occurs.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, you aren't the first. Querying temporal data is a common requirement, especially in data warehouse/data mining.

The relational data model doesn't have any native, built in support for storing or querying "temporal data".

A lot of work has been done; I have a book by C.J.Date et al. that covers the topic decently: "Temporal Data and the Relational Model".  I've also come across several white papers.

---

One typical, reasonably simplistic approach to storing a "history" is to have a "current" table (like the one you already have, and then add a "history" table. Whenever a row is changed (inserted,updated,deleted) in the "current" table, you add a row to the "history" table, along with the date the row was changed. (You can store a copy of the pre-change row, or a copy of the post-change row, or both.)

With this approach, there's no need to add any columns to the "current" table.

Comment: This is what I am currently thinking about. I am a little worried that the history table will get very big very fast if there are either a lot of users or a lot of "events" which need to be timestamped in the history table. Probably not a worry for less than 5000 users though.